# Docker PHP ext enable command failing

Tags: php, docker, xdebug, pecl

What is required to have `docker-php-ext-...` commands available? I am creating an Alpine image

```
FROM alpine:3.12

RUN apk update && \
    # Add support for PHP7.4.
    apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community \
    php php7-fpm nginx composer git 
    ....

# PHPIZE dependencies + xdebug
RUN apk add --no-cache autoconf file g++ gcc libc-dev make pkgconf re2c \
    php7-pecl-xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-install xdebug

...
```

But I am getting `/bin/sh: docker-php-ext-install: not found`.

How can I run the command?
Also, can `apk add php7-pecl-xdebug` replace installing `pecl` as a dependency and requiring the extension that way?

Comment: You probably want the image `php:fpm-alpine` instead of `alpine:3.12`. You also shouldn't try to pack both, nginx and php into a single container.

Comment: Do you split nginx and php on production as well?

Comment: yes it's even more important to split services in production

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using vanilla alpine image.
`docker-php-ext-*` commands exist only in [php-alpine image](https://hub.docker.com/_/php?tab=tags&page=1&name=alpine)

For example, replace your `FROM` to something like:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine
```

Comment: What makes those images have the command? Is it a bash executable or? Can I see the definition of what it actually does?

Comment: @Norgul https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer and https://hub.docker.com/layers/php/library/php/fpm-alpine/images/sha256-a150582d04da17db50a89ad5d6bf3560f9bce1c68bfdc2bd40218cdbe7392077?context=explore

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems.

1. As Dmitry said, you are not using the PHP image but the vanilla Alpine image.
2. You try to pack nginx and PHP into a single container.

When you want to orchestrate nginx and PHP, you should use `docker-compose`.

This is an example PHP+nginx `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    nginx:
        restart: always
        image: nginx:latest
        volumes:
            - ./html/:/var/www/html/:cached
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        links:
            - php

    php:
        restart: always
        build:
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        expose:
            - 9000
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www/:cached
```

And this is the PHP `Dockerfile` used:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli

RUN set -xe \
    && apk add --update \
        icu \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .php-deps \
        make \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        $PHPIZE_DEPS \
        zlib-dev \
        icu-dev \
        g++ \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install intl \
    && docker-php-ext-enable intl \
    && { find /usr/local/lib -type f -print0 | xargs -0r strip --strip-all -p 2>/dev/null || true; } \
    && apk del .build-deps \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* /usr/local/lib/php/doc/* /var/cache/apk/*
```

Answer (score 1):

As a secondary solution, you can have a php.ini locally with enabled PHP extension. Mount your local php.ini with the one in the container. For example:

```
  fpm:
    build: docker/php
    volumes:
      - './:/var/www/html'
      - './docker/php/php.ini:/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php.ini'
```